# Haskell typeclass constraint cannot be resolved due to Paterson's conditions

Tags: haskell, typeclass, undecidable-instances

I'm trying to build an AST with indexed nested annotations. I added a typeclass for peeling the annotation at the top-level and tried to provide default instances that effectively says "if you know how to peel an annotation on its own, then you know how to peel an annotation at the particular AST node."

Since one of my tree nodes is a `Nat` indexed Predicate and its parent existentially quantifies this variable, when I try to write the instance for the parent, I get stuck at Paterson's conditions. Namely, I have more type variables in my assertion than I do in the head.

If I turn on `UndecidableInstances`, then GHC cannot unify the variables with kind `Nat`.

If I further turn on `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, then I get a more absurd error where it says it cannot find an instance despite the fact that the instance it is looking for is in the assertion of the type instance.

My questions are:

1. Is this actually a bad instance to write, or is the type checker too conservative?
2. If it is bad or there is no way around the problem, how else can I provide this default peeling behaviour?

Here's minimalish code (I stripped the bits not essential to the type error, so some bits might seem redundant):

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

module Constraint where

data AnnType = ABase

data family PredicateAnn (a :: AnnType)
data instance PredicateAnn (a :: AnnType) = PABase

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data Predicate (n :: Nat) (a :: AnnType) = Predicate
data Literal   (a :: AnnType) = forall n. Literal (Predicate n a)

class PeelableAST (ast :: AnnType -> *) (ann :: AnnType -> AnnType) where
  peel :: ast (ann a) -> ast a

class PeelableAnn (f :: AnnType -> *) (ann :: AnnType -> AnnType) where
  peelA :: f (ann a) -> f a

instance PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann
         => PeelableAST Literal ann where
  peel (Literal predicate) = Literal (peel predicate)

instance PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann => PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann where
  peel Predicate = Predicate
```

Here's the exact error without `UndecidableInstances`:

```
src/Constraint.hs:27:10: error:
• Variable ‘n’ occurs more often
    in the constraint ‘PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann’
    than in the instance head
  (Use UndecidableInstances to permit this)
• In the instance declaration for ‘PeelableAST Literal ann’
   |
27 | instance PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

And here's the one with it:

```
src/Constraint.hs:28:10: error:
• Could not deduce (PeelableAST (Predicate n0) ann)
  from the context: PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann
    bound by an instance declaration:
               forall (n :: Nat) (ann :: AnnType -> AnnType).
               PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann =>
               PeelableAST Literal ann
    at src/Constraint.hs:(28,10)-(29,35)
  The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous
• In the ambiguity check for an instance declaration
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  In the instance declaration for ‘PeelableAST Literal ann’
   |
28 | instance PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Here is the one with `AllowAmbiguousTypes`:

```
 src/Constraint.hs:31:39: error:
• Could not deduce (PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann)
    arising from a use of ‘peel’
  from the context: PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann
    bound by the instance declaration
    at src/Constraint.hs:(29,10)-(30,35)
• In the first argument of ‘Literal’, namely ‘(peel predicate)’
  In the expression: Literal (peel predicate)
  In an equation for ‘peel’:
      peel (Literal predicate) = Literal (peel predicate)
   |
31 |   peel (Literal predicate) = Literal (peel predicate)
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**EDIT:**

As Daniel Wagner suggests one solution is to make `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` an assertion in `PeelableAST Literal ann` instance. However, I never use `peelA` defined by PeelableAnn in `PeelableAST Literal ann` definition and I'd like this instance to behave as the default behaviour and be able to overwrite it by directly providing a `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` instance. In other words, peeling might be inherently contextual.

Since `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` is required by `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann`, I feel that GHC should be able to find and satisfy this condition.

I can simply have a bogus `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` instance only to be ignored by the more specific one, but that is quite hacky

Answer (score 3):

In your `PeelableAST Literal ann` instance, you use the `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` instance. If the type-checker wants to use that instance, it must verify its precondition, namely, that `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` holds. But it doesn't know this, because you have not made it a precondition of your `PeelableAST Literal ann` instance.

That's okay; it's easy to fix, and lets you avoid an ambiguous type entirely. Just add the precondition it's worried about as a precondition for you `PeelableAST Literal ann` instance. Indeed, since it's now the precondition for both instances, you can then also drop the `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` precondition, as it's implied by this new and stronger condition. So:

```
instance PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann => PeelableAST Literal ann where
    peel (Literal predicate) = Literal (peel predicate)
```

You can then delete `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, though `UndecidableInstances` is still needed because `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` is not obviously structurally smaller than `PeelableAST Literal ann`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I realised that solution myself, but I found it a bit unsatisfactory. I feel like GHC should be able to figure out from the `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` instance that `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` should hold. Especially because these are intended as default instances and I should be able to write a `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` instance for a particular `ann` and let that be picked up by the default  `PeelableAST Literal ann` instance. This does not work if `PeelableAST Liberal ann` also requires a `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` instance.

Comment: @Madgen Ah, I suspect there is a second misunderstanding here: from the precondition you wrote, we know `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann`, but inside the `PeelableAST Literal ann` instance, you unwrap an existential and so require a `PeelableAST (Predicate n') ann` for some `n'` which is not known to be equal to `n`! So upgrading the precondition from `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` to `PeelableAnn PredicateAnn ann` is essentially giving you an upgrade from `exists n. PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` to `forall n. PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` -- at which point we can choose `n ~ n'` as needed.

Comment: @Madgen In other words your current approach is doomed. You could recover by having `Literal` wrap an instance of `PeelableAST` for you, but then you won't be able to make `Literal`s for which you don't have the appropriate `PeelableAST`, and you would have to abandon your current `PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann` catch-all instance in favor of more specific ones. If that sounds interesting I'll be happy to add a small snippet about how.

Comment: I think that might work. Does it amount to just changing the definition of `Literal` so that I have `forall n ann. PeelableAST (Predicate n) ann => Literal ...`? Still not super ideal if that's the case though as I also want an analogous `Decorable` and one can pack only so many typeclasses into datatype...

Comment: @Madgen Yes, that's exactly right -- though you probably want to leave the `ann` out of the `forall`.